# How to access custom metadata in Firebase Security Rule for storage

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I'm stuck with an issue where I can't find information. It seems like not a lot of people are using custom metadata with firebase and I can't find clear documentation about it.

So, basically, what I'm doing is to give the file I'm uploading a new custom metadata that I called GroupID and in firebase security rule I'm checking that this GroupID is equal to something in the path of my file. Here is my rule :

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    // Get/Set a challenge in storage
    match /Groups/{GroupID}/Challenges/{ChallengeType}/{PlayerID}/{File} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == PlayerID
                   && request.resource.size < 25 * 1024 * 1024
                   && request.resource.metadata['GroupID'] == GroupID;
    }
  }
}
```

I was able to make sure that the issue comes from the last condition. I use all of these variants :

```
request.resource.metadata['GroupID'] == GroupID;
request.resource.metadata["GroupID"] == GroupID;
request.resource.metadata.GroupID == GroupID;
resource.metadata['GroupID'] == GroupID;
resource.metadata["GroupID"] == GroupID;
resource.metadata.GroupID == GroupID;
```

Also, I was able to make know that GroupID is a string while all metadata['GroupID'] and their variants are not a string. So the issue might comme from here.
However, when I'm creating the metadata in unity, they are created as string.

One last thing, using the simulator of Firebase Security Rules works.

You might need my unity side code for the metadata:

```
MetadataChange fileMetadata = new MetadataChange()
            {
                CustomMetadata = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "GroupID" , group_ID },
                }
            };
```

So am I doing something wrong in C# or in the Firebase Security Rules?

Thanks in advance for you help !

Adrien

EDIT 1 : I forgot but when I'm not checking metadata, I can put the file in firebase storage and metadata are here:

[image]

Comment: From looking at [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-storage%5D%5Bfirebase-security%5D+metadata) your rules and code look fine at first glance. If you only use this check `request.resource.metadata.GroupID == GroupID` does it reject the write?

Comment: Yep the write is still rejected, always with the same error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Firebase.Storage.StorageException: Permission denied. Could not perform this operation  Http Code: 403
This does not happened if I remove it