# Cannot make custom metadata in a Firebase Cloud Storage security rule work as expected

Tags: firebase-storage, firebase-security

Issue is effectively identical to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68601031/how-to-access-custom-metadata-in-firebase-security-rule-for-storage) which was left unresolved and I'm new to SO so couldn't comment to ask if a resolution was ever found (apologies for posting a redundant question). My specific case:

```js
    match /profilePhotos/{pathAsUserUid}/{photoFileName} {
      allow create: if request.resource.metadata.userUid == pathAsUserUid;
    }
```

returns false when I believe it should return true. The metadata has been written correctly to Storage and appears in https://console.cloud.google.com/storage as expected e.g., (key 2) userUid has a value of LjCZ3ONBTqPEIhNTXt2pxMDWkvJ2.

[custom metadata as it appears in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oH5W.png)

Forcing a result via specific test cases clearly shows request.resource.metadata.userUid simply isn't working as expected. For example, (for testing only)

```js
      allow create: if 'LjCZ3ONBTqPEIhNTXt2pxMDWkvJ2' == pathAsUserUid;
```

works as expected (returns true) however,

```js
      allow create: if request.resource.metadata.userUid == 'LjCZ3ONBTqPEIhNTXt2pxMDWkvJ2';
```

doesn't work as expected (returns false).

*ADDITION 1*

[Screen snapshot of console including path to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoZPB.png)

*ADDITION 2*
Here's the code for uploading the profile photo. PUser is a straightforward user-data class with a uid set (not shown below but thoroughly tested) from the FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid.

```dart
  void onSubmitted(String? value) async {
    bool success = true;

    // pUSer contains everything *except* the profile photo (held by pUser.profilePhotoXFile)
    // upload the photo to cloud storage then get the photo's url
    XFile profilePhotoXFile = widget.pUser.profilePhotoXFile as XFile;
    final profilePhotoMetadata = SettableMetadata(
      contentType: profilePhotoXFile.mimeType,
      customMetadata: {
        'user': widget.pUser.fullName!,
        'userUid': widget.pUser.uid! // <-- @Dharmaraj this is where the userUid metadata is set
      },
    );

    final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
    final profilePhotoRef = storageRef
        .child('profilePhotos/${widget.pUser.uid}/${profilePhotoXFile.name}');

    setState(() {
      screenMode = ScreenMode.wait;
      screenMessage = 'Uploading profile photo...';
    });

    try {
      if (kIsWeb) {
        Uint8List profilePhotoBytes = await profilePhotoXFile.readAsBytes();
        TaskSnapshot upload = await profilePhotoRef.putData(
          profilePhotoBytes,
          profilePhotoMetadata,
        );

        widget.pUser.profilePhotoURL = await upload.ref.getDownloadURL();
      } else {
        throw const PlainliException('Only web is (currently) supported for image upload.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      success = false;
      plainliBanner(
          context: context,
          message: 'Error uploading profile photo. error = $e');
    }

    if (!success) {
      setState(() {
        screenMode = ScreenMode.message;
        screenMessage = 'There was an error uploading your photo.';
      });
      return;
    }

    // *merge* data{} into Firestore
    setState(() {
      screenMode = ScreenMode.wait;
      screenMessage = 'Registering...';
    });

    Map<String, dynamic> data = widget.pUser.toMap();
    CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> collectionRef =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

    try {
      await collectionRef
          .doc(widget.pUser.uid)
          .set(data, SetOptions(merge: true));
    } catch (e) {
      success = false;
      plainliBanner(
          context: context,
          message: 'Error merging data into Firestore. Error: $e');
    }

    if (!success) {
      setState(() {
        screenMode = ScreenMode.message;
        screenMessage =
            'There was an error uploading your profile information.';
      });
      return;
    }

    if (!mounted) return;
    plainliSnackbar(context: context, message: 'Registration complete');

    Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);

    // this allows the wrapper to get notified that all the user data has
    // been successfully collected
    Provider.of<PUserProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .allRequiredUserDataExists = true;
  }
```

And here are the Cloud Storage rules.

```js
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
  
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
    
    match /profilePhotos/{pathAsUserUid}/{photo} {
      allow read, write: if isAdmin();
      allow get, create, update: if profilePhotoBelongsToUser(pathAsUserUid);
    }
    
    function isSignedin() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }   
    
    function isAdmin() {
      let isUserSignedin = isSignedin();
      let isUserRoleAdmin = request.auth.token.isAdmin;
      return isUserSignedin && isUserRoleAdmin;
    }

    function profilePhotoBelongsToUser(pathAsUserUid) {
      let isUserSignedin = isSignedin();
      //let metadataUidMatchesPath = request.resource.metadata.userUid == pathAsUserUid;
      let metadataUidMatchesPath = true; // <-- @Dharmaraj this is a temp get-around until we can sort out why the line above fails
      let authUidMatchesPath = request.auth.uid == pathAsUserUid;
      return isUserSignedin && metadataUidMatchesPath && authUidMatchesPath;
    }   
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of that file from your FIrebase storage console so we can see complete path to the file? I suspect the wildcard placement could be the issue. The var name `pathAsUserUid` make it seem like there's more path segments just than the UID.

Comment: Hi @Dharmaraj, just added the screenshot, really appreciate another set of eyes on this. Cheers.

Comment: This rule looks fine to me. Can you please explain what you are doing here? The rule is for creating files `allow create`. Now if this is failing, how was the image uploaded at first place? Also can you share the code you are using to upload the file? Just to ensure that path and metadata is there is valid.

Comment: Q. "Can you please explain what you are doing here?"
A. Verifying that when a user does a get, create, or update on a profile photo that the profile photo belongs to that user. Other checks are in place but, since metadata is available, we wanted to take advantage of that additional check.

Q. "Now if this is failing, how was the image uploaded at first place?"
A. See the Cloud Storage security rules function 'profilePhotoBelongsToUser' available in the latest edit. You'll see that as a temporary get-around I bypassed this metadata check and thus was able to upload profile photos / images.